# Is it possible to navigate to a video in a YouTube playlist by index?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

Here is an example url of a video in a YouTube playlist:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1uW3qMFA9Ho&list=PLUl4u3cNGP60hI9ATjSFgLZpbNJ7myAg6&index=1
```

We have an identifier that points to the list and the index of the video in this list.

Is it possible to navigate to a video if you know the `list` and the `index`, but not the video id?

If I leave out the video id it just redirects to the home page:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLUl4u3cNGP60hI9ATjSFgLZpbNJ7myAg6&index=1
```

---

An example use-case for this is that if I have a very large playlist and I want to find a video somewhere in the middle it's easier to navigate to by index than scrolling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You asked:

> Is it possible to navigate to a video if you know the list and the index, but not the video id?

No. At least, **not directly**.

**SOLUTION**

Lets say that (as per your example) you want to go to the `6th video` of  playlist `PLUl4u3cNGP60hI9ATjSFgLZpbNJ7myAg6`

Try the following:

Place any single character like `+*-_$&=@06abgk` after `.../watch?v=`

Your example will become something like

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=+&list=PLUl4u3cNGP60hI9ATjSFgLZpbNJ7myAg6&index=5
```

OR

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gg&list=PLUl4u3cNGP60hI9ATjSFgLZpbNJ7myAg6&index=5
```

YouTube will *"think"* for a while, guess and correct your link based on your playlist and index number and finally redirect you to

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N3I2ZLbh6zQ&list=PLUl4u3cNGP60hI9ATjSFgLZpbNJ7myAg6&index=6
```

Please notice that **the index number used is -1 the desired one**.
**We use `index=5` to get to `index=6`**

---

***Notes***

1. One cannot use `index=0` to get to `index=1`.
2. If one uses an index number greater than the ones existing in the playlist (like `index=745`), it will default to `index=2`
3. Instead of using just one single character, as many as up to 10 characters can be used. This means (if already in the playlist) you can just delete a couple of the current video ID's characters and replace the index number -1

Comment: That is very interesting behavior. Thank you for your answer, this is very useful. I was initially thinking about creating an extension that would use Javascript to circumvent the problem by targeting the element and simulating a click. I'm glad I never got around to it, because this approach is a lot more elegant.

Comment: Very interesting indeed. Glad I could help (even after such a long time). Thank you for accepting.